# Find all the solutions to the following system of equations.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

\begin{cases} x=1.5x(1-x)-0.7xy \\ y=y+2xy-0.6y\\ \end{cases} Where (x,y)= ( , )has the smallest x-value (x,y)=( , ) and (x,y)= ( , ) has the largest x-value.

The furthest I got was the second equation simplifies to y=0 and x=0.3. I plugged y=0 into the first equation and found (x,y)= ($\frac{1}{3}$,0). I tried to plug in the x value into the first equation but the (x,y) I get is incorrect. I tried to find the smallest x and largest x combinations but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

The second equation gives two answers: $y = 0$ OR $x = 0.3$, not "and".  so with $y = 0$ the first equation becomes $x = 1.5x(1-x)$ which has $x=0$ as one solution and $x = 1/3$.  So two solutions are $(0,0)$ and $(1/3, 0)$.

If instead you take $x = 0.3$ from the second equation, you get an equation for $y$.  Since $x ≠ 0$ you can divide it out to get $1 = 1.5(0.7) - (0.7)y$ which gives $y = -.05/-0.7$ or $y = 1/14$.  So another solution is $(0.3, 1/14)$.  Those three are all the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The second equations two solutions are $y=0$ and $x=0.3$ are separate solutions.  Plug either into the first equation to get possible solutions.

For $y=0$, the first equation leads to $x=0$ or $x=\frac{1}{3}$.

For $x=0.3$, the first equation leads to $y=\frac{1}{14}$

To answer the original question $(0,0)$ and $(\frac{1}{3},0)$ have the smallest and largest $x$ values.

Comment: that's what I put and I still got it wrong.

Comment: What are the right answers?

Comment: The answers were correct the platform was incorrect. I apologize.